# get all user's contact list (including phone number) from google login in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-contacts-api

I am trying to get the contact number of all the user's contacts through google sign in. I am getting contact name, email and other details but not the contact number. I am specifically trying contacts API v3.

[this official link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#working_with_contact_group)

gives a way to get contact details (including phone number) but I am not really sure how to do that in javascript. I googled around and found that people are using contacts API v2 and v1 to get this information. But even there I couldn't find any suitable example. My current implementation using google api (gapi) gives me contacts in this format

> displayName: "Jamie Lannister"
>   etag: ""XXXXXXXX-YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY/Wl9XXXXXXXXXXXXXZ9-cJsx-wUY""
>   id: "107108760XXXXXXXXXXXX"
>   image: Object
>   url: "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-9Iyxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxk/xxxxxx-xxx/photo.jpg?sz=50"
>   **proto**: Object
>   kind: "plus#person"
>   objectType: "person"
>   url: "https://plus.google.com/107108760XXXXXXXXXXXX

I got this from this [link](https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/) and this [link](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people).

My question is it really possible to get a user's google+ or google contacts with phone numbers? If yes please answer here. Is there any other way to do this?

Oh by the way, this question is not eligible for bounty yet. Correct answer gets +50 bounty in next 2 days.

Comment: Never mind I got it. I am getting all the contacts.

Comment: How did you get the phone number?  Please share!

Comment: there you go I have added an answer, sorry for the delay, I just saw your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following **javascript** function (httpGet) to get the google contacts with name and number. The url i passed in the "theUrl" param is : "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/user.email@gmail.com/full?access_token="+authToken+'&max-results=9999'"

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: theUrl,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (xml) {               
                $(xml).find('entry').each(function(){
                    var name = '';
                    var number = '';
                    $(this).find("gd\\:phoneNumber").each(function(){
                        number = $(this).text();
                    });
                    $(this).find("title").each(function(){
                        name = $(this).text();
                    });

                    if(number!=null && number.length>0)
                    {
                        number = number.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
                        userContacts.push(name+'-'+number);
                    }
                });


            },
        });
    }
```

Explanation:
by default google returns a particular number of contacts, to get all the contacts pass a really big number in max-results parameter (hence the 9999).
authToken is what you get after you authorize the user.
email address: after getting authtoken you an query for email address as well. here is how i did it:

```
function getEmail(){
        gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function() {
            var request = gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get();
            request.execute(getEmailCallback);
        });
    }

function getEmailCallback(obj){
        email = '';
        if (obj['email']) {
            email = obj['email'];
            //here you get the email address of the user who just signed in
        }
    }
```

the gapi here is google's api javascript object. add this script and you are good to go

```
script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"/ (add jQuery script too)
```

Without the ajax call in httpGet(), you will receive a cross domain compliance error. What you receive after httpGet of the mentioned url is an xml file, the whole success lot inside the httpGet() method is for parsing that xml, you will also receive a bunch of other info, if required parse those too (I only needed contact number and name). if you want a google account with contacts just log in to [google contacts](http://www.google.com/contacts) and add some test phone numbers there.

Needless to say you will also need client Id, secret, API key etc for this. Please go to the link provided below for details. the user contacts var in httpGet() contains all the user contacts separated by hyphen. The regex pattern in httpGet() is to pick only numbers from contact number or else you might get something like this (123) 456 7890.

more details [straight from google](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/)